# issue in console application starting from a command line in c#

Tags: c#, cmd, process, console-application

I have a console application which start a process and execute a command.

```
 public static void ExecuteCommand(string CommandScript)
        {
            string strCmdText;
            strCmdText = "/C " + CommandScript;           
            var process = Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
```

Am passing one argument to the console application
when I call the application from the application folder using CMD
like

> C:\Program Files\Normand Info\RADV Web\radvwebbackup.exe abcd

it is working properly
but when am calling like

> c:\users\Administrator>"C:\Program Files\Normand Info\RADV Web\radvwebbackup.exe" abcd

from CMD it is starting but ExecuteCommand() method not doing the command execution

what might be the reason ?

Comment: All `ExecuteCommand` doing is starting CMD.exe. What `command execution` is it supposed to do?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have a command to do back up of database using another application, which will start by ExecuteCommand() method

Comment: `what might be the reason ?` - 1) encoding 2) the fact you are running a console application from a console application 3) permissions 4) some other fluke in the code that you haven't provided completely. This isn't a mind reading service. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).